# Drawing Explosions Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, animation, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on a game ([beta here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.embeddedmicro.wormholebeta)) and I am drawing explosions using an image I have. As the explosion ages it increases in size and becomes more transparent until it is gone.

My problem is that this seems to be the bottle neck it my code. I easily hit 60FPS but when explosions start happening this can easily drop down to 30FPS. If I disable only the explosions I get a constant 60FPS.

Is there something I can do with OpenGL to render these more effectively?

I am drawing them all sequentially and I only bind the texture and vertices once.

Any general stuff I should be aware of for optimizing OpenGL calls?

My code is in Java, would re-writing this part in native code help?

I have a main draw function that draws all the explosions

```
public void draw() {
    GLES20.glUniform1i(GraphicsEngine.uEnableVortex, 0);
    for (Boom boom : mBooms) {
        boom.drawCloud();
    }
    mHugeBoom.drawCloud();
    GLES20.glUniform1i(GraphicsEngine.uEnableVortex, 1);

    // Prepare the data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GraphicsEngine.aPositionHandle, 3,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, mVerticesBuffer);
    GraphicsEngine.clearShape();

    // Disable textures
    GLES20.glUniform1i(GraphicsEngine.uEnableTextureHandle, 0);

    GLES20.glLineWidth(2.0f);

    for (Boom boom : mBooms) {
        boom.drawSparks();
    }
    mHugeBoom.drawSparks();
}
```

Then for "booms"

```
public void drawCloud(){
        if (mActive) {
            float pDone = mTotalTime / 600.0f / mSize;
            if (pDone <= 1.0f) {
                mBurst.setColor(mRGBA);
                mBurst.draw(mMMatrix);
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawSparks(){
        if (mActive) {
            for (Particle particle : mParticles) {
                particle.draw();
            }
        }
    }
```

The actual drawing

```
public void draw(float[] MMatrix, boolean setColor) {
    // Prepare the triangle data
    GraphicsEngine.setShape(mShape);

    if (mTextureId != -1) {
        GraphicsEngine.bindTexture(mTextureId);
        if (mCustomTex) {
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GraphicsEngine.aTexCoordHandle, 2,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, mTextureBuffer);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GraphicsEngine.aTexCoordHandle);
            GraphicsEngine.clearTexture();
        } else {
            GraphicsEngine.setTexture(mShape);
        }
    } else {
        GLES20.glUniform1i(GraphicsEngine.uEnableTextureHandle, 0);
    }

    // Apply a ModelView Projection transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GraphicsEngine.uMMatrixHandle, 1, false,
            MMatrix, 0);

    if (setColor)
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(GraphicsEngine.uColorHandle, 1, mRGBA, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
            GraphicsEngine.getNumIndicies(mShape),
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GraphicsEngine.getIndicies(mShape));

}
```

Code that prevents reloading of loaded textures

```
public static void setShape(int i) {
    if (mState.shape != i) {
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false, 12, mShapes[i].vertices);
        mState.shape = i;
    }
}

public static void setTexture(int i) {
    if (mState.texture != i) {
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GraphicsEngine.aTexCoordHandle, 2,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, mShapes[i].texture);
        mState.texture = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java's the way to go on Android. I wouldn't imagine a device would slowdown from layering a few transparent images so I would make sure the code handling how your explosions behaved wasn't the problem.  Can you post some code from your Explosion?

Comment: I added the relevant code. Let me know if you need any more.